# Remove square brackets from string findall output that is checking a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

print(df)

       Items
    0  Product A + Product B + Product C   
    1  Product A + Product B + Product B1 + Product C1
```

I am using the following code to see if items contained within the column are contained within a list:

```
My_Items = ['Product B1', 'Product C']

Item_mask = df.Items.str.findall('|'.join(My_Items )).str.len()
df['Item_list'] = df.Items.str.findall('|'.join(My_Items))
```

This gives me a new column that looks like this:

```
   Items                                                 Item_list
0  Product A + Product B + Product C                     [Product C]
1  Product A + Product B + Product B1 + Product C1       [Product B1]
```

Does anyone know how I can get the Item list to just give me the item i am searching for without the [] brackets?

The desired output is below:

```
   Items                                                 Item_list
0  Product A + Product B + Product C                     Product C
1  Product A + Product B + Product B1 + Product C1       Product B1
```

I have tried converting it to a string using:

```
df['Item_list'] = df.Items.str.findall('|'.join(My_Items)).astype(str)
```

But this gives me the data like this,  e.g ['Product C'], which is not what I want either.

I have also tried an iterrows solution, which gives me my desired output but it takes far too long to complete, the real data source is very large!

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Comment: Can't you just pass `[0]` to your `df['Item_list']` ?

Comment: Brackets are list notation.  If you want only the string inside, then either don't use a list at a ll, or access the desired list location with a subscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `.apply(','.join)` to your `findall` command, like this:

```
df['Item_list'] = df.Items.str.findall('|'.join(My_Items)).apply(','.join)
```

**Output:**

```
                                             Items             Item_list
0                Product A + Product B + Product C             Product C
1  Product A + Product B + Product B1 + Product C1             Product B1
```